# Parellel-To-Plane Version of RegionDistance

Tags: computational-geometry, synthetic-geometry

`RegionDistance` basically calculates distance between points P and Q=`RegionNearest[Reg,P]`:

[image: RegionDistance]

I need to find a way to find function of distance **parallel to XY plane**:

[image: Directional RegionDiatance]

And, I need it to operate in the way `RegionDistance` does, so that something like `DirectionalRegionDistance[Reg]` would give a distance function that could be applied repeatedly to different points.

Could someone help me out with this please ?

**Upd:** The original question was misleadingly formulated. I don't need "distance in a known direction". Instead, I need function that outputs sort of "distance parallel to plane", or, alternative naming - "distance perpenducular to a vector".

Comment: For the first part, I can envision the following: 1) Construct an `InfiniteLine` passing through $p$ and parallel to the direction you need. 2) Find `RegionIntersection` between the line and your object. 4) Calculate `EuclideanDistance`s between all intersection points and your point $p$, and take the shortest. The second part, i.e. the distance function, seems orders of magnitude more complex. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried experimenting with RegionNearest and taking [[3]] of it to compare it with Pz. Didnt manage it to take off.

Answer (score 7):

This is a crude implementation using `RegionIntersection` together with `InfinitePlane`.

```
DirectionalRegionDistance[reg_, v1_, v2_][p_] := 
 Module[{line, intersection},
  line = InfinitePlane[p, {v1, v2}];
  intersection = RegionIntersection[reg, line];
  If[Head@intersection === EmptyRegion, Infinity,
   RegionNearest[intersection, p]
   ]
  ]

reg = Sphere[];
p = {3/2, 3/2, 1/3};

(* Distance in XY plane *)
DirectionalRegionDistance[reg, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}][p]
(* {2/3, 2/3, 1/3} *)

(* Distance in YZ plane *)
DirectionalRegionDistance[reg, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}][p]
(* Infinity *)
```

This function takes a region `reg`, and two plane vectors `v1` and `v2`.

Answer (score 5):

### Edit

For arbitrary normal of hyperplane.

```
Clear[reg, normal, pt, dist, sol, pt1];
reg = Ball[];
normal = {.1, -0.2, 1};
(* normal={0,0,1} *)
pt = {3, 4, .5};
dist = SignedRegionDistance[reg];
sol = NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, 
    pt], {x, y, z} ∈ Hyperplane[normal, pt], 
   dist@{x, y, z} <= 0}, {x, y, z}]
pt1 = {x, y, z} /. sol[[2]]
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.95], reg, {Opacity[.6], Hyperplane[normal, pt]}, 
  Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[pt], Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
  Arrow[{pt, pt1}]}, ViewPoint -> {3, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

### Two-dimensional conditional restrictions problem

```
Clear[reg, h, pt, dist, sol, pt1];
reg = Ball[];
h = .5;
pt = {2, 2, h};
dist = SignedRegionDistance[reg];
sol = NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[{x, y, h}, pt], 
   dist@{x, y, h} <= 0}, {x, y}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
pt1 = {x, y, h} /. sol[[2]]
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.95], 
  reg, {Opacity[.2], InfinitePlane[pt, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, Blue,
   AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[pt], Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
  Arrow[{pt, pt1}]}]
```

[image]

### One-dimensional conditional restrictions problem

We use `NDSolve` to descript the path from one point `pt` along the direction `dir`,and use `WhenEvent` to find such `t0`.

```
Clear[reg, pt, pt1, dir, sol, t0];
reg = Ball[];
pt = {2, 2, 2};
dir = Normalize@{-1.3, -2.1, -2};
dist = SignedRegionDistance[reg];
sol = Reap@
   NDSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]} == dir, {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == pt, 
     WhenEvent[
      dist@{x[t], y[t], z[t]} == 0, {Sow@t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {x, 
     y, z}, {t, 0, 10}];
t0 = sol[[2, 1, 1]];
pt1 = TranslationTransform[t0*dir]@pt;
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], reg, Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
   Point[pt], Point@pt1, Red, Arrow[{pt, pt1}]}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[TranslationTransform[t*dir]@pt, {t, 0, t0}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the OP's question (first, I did it too, it's a slightly misleading naming). He doesn't want a distance in a specific direction, but parallel to some plane. Therefore, your ``dir`` is actually unknown.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I will re-formulate my question.

Answer (score 4):

We can still use "RegionDistance" if we calculate the intersection between the x-y plane and your region.

E.g. if we define r1 as a ball at {0,2,0} :

```
r1 = Region[Ball[{2, 0, 0}, 1]];
```

we may define a distance function that delivers the distance parallel to the x-y plane:

```
dist = (RegionDistance[RegionIntersection[r1,Region[InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, #[[3]]}, {1, 0, #[[3]]}, {0, 
          1, #[[3]]}}]]]][#]) &
```

If we apply this to the origin:

```
dist[{0,0,0}]
(* 1 *)
```

And if we apply it to the point: {0,1,0}:

```
dist[{0, 1, 0}]
(* Sqrt[2 (3 - Sqrt[5])] *)
```

Or:

```
dist[{0, 0, 1/2}]
(* 1/2 Sqrt[19 - 8 Sqrt[3]] *)
```

Note that it does not evaluate if the intersection has dimension 0.

If you want to check, if there is an non empty intersection, it becomes  slightly more complex. We may e.g. first define a function that returns a function which returns either the distance or "Not available" if the intersection is empty:

```
getfun[reg_] := Module[{inter, dist},
  (inter = 
     RegionIntersection[reg, 
      Region[InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, #[[3]]}, {1, 0, #[[3]]}, {0, 
          1, #[[3]]}}]]];
    Switch[dist = RegionDistance[Evaluate@inter, #], _?NumberQ, 
     dist, _, "Not available"]) &
  ];
```

This will return a function that gives the horizontal distance to a point or "not available". E.g. the distance from a point {0,1,0.4} to the above ball:

```
dist = getfun[Region[Ball[{2, 0, 0}, 1]]];
dist[{0, 1, 0.4}]
(* 1.31955 *)
```

Comment: Shouldn't ``InfinitePlane`` go through $P$ and not through $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Sure, you are right. I corrected my error.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be what I desired. How does one implement the cheking if there's empty intersection?

Comment: I added a piece that checks for a non empty intersection.